# Execute and Open stored Procedure in vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a question, I have a form with a button that loads a Stored procedure in VBA access, I implemented code to execute this stored procedure with one parameter, how can I open it immediately when I execute. I wrote some code but it doesn't work:

```
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim stDocName As String
 Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

    strSQL = "EXEC Verificare_amenzi_firma '" & Me.CodF & "'"

       Call AttServ(strSQL, rst) 'Execute query

stDocName = "Verificare_amenzi_firma"
DoCmd.OpenStoredProcedure stDocName, acViewNormal, acEdit
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `Stored Procedure`? Access doesn't necessarily have them.

Comment: i have an Access interface connected to SQL tables

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800727/ms-access-call-sql-server-stored-procedure