# Stored Procedure with access VBA Button

Tags: ms-access, stored-procedures, vba, sql-server-2014

I need to execute a stored procedure in MS Access 2013. I use Access as front end interface which is connected to two databases. One database has a few stored procedures. I need to execute those with push of button in the Access.

Database is connected through SQL Server authentication. I started a button in Access and here is the VBA code behind this button. It's empty and just simply need more code to get it running:

```
Private Sub UpdateItems_Click()        
End Sub
```

Here are the parameters to establish the connection and stored procedure name:

1. Server Name: `BOX\SQL2014`
2. User Name: sa
3. Password: 123456PS
4. Database: SixBit
5. Stored procedure name: `spRefreshItems`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800727/ms-access-call-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: Note: you should ***NEVER EVER*** use the `sa` account ! Not even in testing. Just **don't do it!**