# Pass Access table's date value as a parameter to SQL Server's stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, pass-through

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2016 named `usp_createRecord` that takes in 2 parameters `start_date` and `end_date`.

I have a table in MS Access named `MyReport` that has 8 columns- 2 of them being `startDate` and `endDate`.

I need to pass the date value from MS Access as a parameter to SQL Server's stored procedure. Execute the stored procedure and display it in the MS Access 
workbook.

Hope I was clear.

Comment: What part(s) of this do you need help with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access call SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800727/ms-access-call-sql-server-stored-procedure)

Comment: EXEC  usp_createRecord '2017-02-01','2017-03-01'
When I run this as pass through query I get result
But I want the dates to be passed dynamically from table 'MyReport'
Thank you for your time.

Comment: OK. We would need to see some code in order to help. Just stating you want this dynamic does let anybody help you write the code.

Comment: I usually do this in VBA.  It sounds like you want the results of each row of a query like `select start_date, end_date from MyReport` passed into a pass-through query like `exec usp_createRecord qry!start_date, qry!end_date`, but pass-through queries don't reference Access queries like that.

Comment: I suppose not. Thanks anyways Beth and Sean for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need a query with a field calling a VBA function passing your parameters which returns the value from a pass-through query whose `SQL` is determined at runtime.
If you're calling a function like that for a large number of rows, it will be slow.

For example, you need a pass-through query with your connection to your SQL Server.  I'll call that `qry_PT_createRecord`.

Then you need a `public function` in VBA with your two `date` parameters passed in which modifies the pass-through query's `sql` property, like:

```
Public Function g_createRecord(startDate As Date, endDate As Date) As Integer
    Dim db As Database
    Dim qdef As QueryDef
    Dim sql As String

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set qdef = db.QueryDef("qry_PT_createRecord")
    qdef.sql = "exec usp_createRecord " & startDate & "," & endDate
    g_createRecord = qdef.Execute
End Function
```

Then you need a query to display your fields from `MyReport`, call the function, and return the sp's value, if there is one.  I'll call that query `qry_createRecord`.  The SQL will look like:

```
Select 
 ID, 
 startDate, 
 endDate, 
 g_createRecord(startdate,enddate)
from 
 myReport
```

Comment: not sure why this solution was downvoted when there's no alternative posted